# Delphi FMX TListBox slow with large lists

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistbox, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm loading 2,000 names into an FMX TListBox and it is taking far too long (like 35 seconds or more).

Here is the test code:

```
procedure TDocWindow.DEBUGAddLotsOfStringsToList;
var
  theTimeAtStart: Integer;
  J: Integer;

begin
  ListBox1.Clear;

  theTimeAtStart := TThread.GetTickCount;

  for J := 1 to 2200 do
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(j.toString);
    end;

  ShowMessage('There were ' + J.ToString + ' strings added to the list in ' + (TThread.GetTickCount - theTimeAtStart).ToString + ' milliseconds.');
end;
```

Is there something about TListBox that makes it too slow for a few thousand strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` reduced the runtime on my system from 25 seconds to about 125 ms.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  theTimeAtStart: Integer;
  J: Integer;
begin
  theTimeAtStart := TThread.GetTickCount;

  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;

  try
    ListBox1.Clear;

    for J := 1 to 2200 do
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(j.ToString());
    end;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
  ShowMessage('There were ' + J.ToString + ' strings added to the list in ' + (TThread.GetTickCount - theTimeAtStart).ToString + ' milliseconds.');
end;
```

Comment: `Clear()` should be inside the `(Begin|End)Update` pair, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Fixed. Thanks. I missed that when I added the Begin/EndUpdate block.

Comment: @KenWhite: Why do you put the `BeginUpdate` after `try`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: For the same reason I accidentally left `Clear` before the `BeginUpdate`. :-) Fixed. Thanks.